# PyYAML dumps dict using leading question marks for keys and prints values next line

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

When dumping dict with quite long keys I get something like this:

```
? ns=4;s=|var|CODESYS Control for Raspberry Pi SL.Application.GVL.Data.DateTime.NewDateTime
: 2018-10-11 17:59
? ns=4;s=|var|CODESYS Control for Raspberry Pi SL.Application.GVL.Data.DateTime.SetNewDateTime
: 2018-10-11 17:59
? ns=4;s=|var|CODESYS Control for Raspberry Pi SL.Application.GVL.Data.FeedFlow.Auger[].Ascend
: 2018-10-11 17:59
? ns=4;s=|var|CODESYS Control for Raspberry Pi SL.Application.GVL.Data.FeedFlow.Auger[].Descend
: 2018-10-11 17:59
```

Instead I would like to:

- not have leading ? for every dict element
- not have the key printed in the next line

Something like this:

```
ns=4;s=|var|CODESYS Control for Raspberry Pi SL.Application.GVL.Data.DateTime.NewDateTime: 2018-10-11 17:59
ns=4;s=|var|CODESYS Control for Raspberry Pi SL.Application.GVL.Data.DateTime.SetNewDateTime: 2018-10-11 17:59
ns=4;s=|var|CODESYS Control for Raspberry Pi SL.Application.GVL.Data.FeedFlow.Auger[].Ascend: 2018-10-11 17:59
ns=4;s=|var|CODESYS Control for Raspberry Pi SL.Application.GVL.Data.FeedFlow.Auger[].Descend: 2018-10-11 17:59
```

How could I accomplish the above?

My current dump command is the following:

```
yaml.dump(
    some_dict, 
    open(shades, 'w+'), 
    default_flow_style=False, 
    width=float("inf")
)
```

Now I'm monkey patching by dumping in a variable content and string replacing as follows:

```
content = content.replace("? ","")
content = content.replace("\n:",":")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, that output is perfectly fine YAML. I loads back to what
you dumped. It doesn't look that nice, but it is necessary to do so
because the keys are long and don't fit on the default line length.

You provide the `width` parameter, but the problem is that
`float("inf")` is not an appropriate value and PyYAML doesn't warn you
about that. You should just use an appropriately large **integer** value
instead as the following code shows (assuming that data is in file
`shades.yaml`):

```
import sys
import yaml

ONEMILLION = 1000**2

with open('shades.yaml') as fp:
    data = yaml.safe_load(fp)
yaml.safe_dump(data, sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False, width=ONEMILLION)
```

output:

```
ns=4;s=|var|CODESYS Control for Raspberry Pi SL.Application.GVL.Data.DateTime.NewDateTime: 2018-10-11 17:59
ns=4;s=|var|CODESYS Control for Raspberry Pi SL.Application.GVL.Data.DateTime.SetNewDateTime: 2018-10-11 17:59
ns=4;s=|var|CODESYS Control for Raspberry Pi SL.Application.GVL.Data.FeedFlow.Auger[].Ascend: 2018-10-11 17:59
ns=4;s=|var|CODESYS Control for Raspberry Pi SL.Application.GVL.Data.FeedFlow.Auger[].Descend: 2018-10-11 17:59
```

And no, you cannot do `ONEMILLION = int(float("inf"))`, you'll get an error.

I am using `safe_dump` here, not because it is necessary, but it is
sufficient, and because it makes it less likely that you use `load()`
which in PyYAML is potentially unsafe.

---

If you want to do the same with ruamel.yaml (disclaimer: I am the
author of that package), e.g. if you need to be YAML 1.2 compatible, or need more control over 
indentation than PyYAML can provide, you can do:

```
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

shades = Path('shades.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.width = ONEMILLION
# next line is not necessary, style is preserved and input is block-style
yaml.default_flow_style=False  
data = yaml.load(shades)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

with same  result.

Comment: this doesn't work if the keys are >= 128 length it seems.

Comment: EDIT: this (the snippet with yaml library) doesn't work if the keys are >= 123 length, see https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/368#issuecomment-1890052845 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197268/pyyaml-yaml-dump-produces-complex-key-for-string-key-122-chars

Comment: @timotheecour You should not be using PyYAML it is a YAML 1.1 parser, outdated in 2009. In ruamel yaml you can set the maximum length for simple keys: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31199123/1307905